# is there any method in python to replace nan in dataframe by string without effect blank cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I have dataframe with values `Na`, `blank` and others. I want to replace `Na` with `noted`  (`string` value)
I want to transform [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfYHc.png) to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUdWj.png) ***without changing blank*** cell.

I already tried

```
df['A']=df['A'].replace(regex=['NaN'], value='needed')
```

and

```
df['A'].replace(regex=['NA'], value='noted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['A'].fillna('noted')
```

---

Alternatively, if `NA` is a string and not `np.nan` then you can use [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df['A'].replace(['NA'], 'noted')
```

Comment: ***i want to replace na value without effecting the other blank cell***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fillna()` method -

`df['A'].fillna('Noted', inplace=True)`

OR

`df['A'] = df['A'].fillna('Noted')`

To change without changing blanks - you can use a mapping function

```
def fillna_not_blanks(value):
    if value.strip() == '':
        return value
    elif value == np.nan:
        return 'Noted'
    else:
        return value

df['A'] = df['A'].map(fillna_not_blanks)
```

Comment: fillna method also changing blank cell too

Comment: Dont use `fillna` - use a function like `fillna_not_blanks` above